# How to set the path of the folder to be created in uwp in C#

Tags: c#, uwp

For example: C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\

There it creates the folder on the desktop

I do not have code, and I have no idea how to do it. And I do not want to use FolderPicker, I want to define in the folder path code

Comment: Are you asking how to get the path of the current user's desktop folder?

Comment: That. I want to have a path destined to create the folder

Comment: What have you tried? What error are you getting? UWP applications are meant to be like phone apps in that they do not allow arbitrary access to operating system APIs (like creating folders) you may have to define permissions to create a folder on the user's desktop.

Comment: I was using folderPicker, but I did not want to open windows explorer. To choose where I want to create the folder.
I already want a place set for her to be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, UWP applications are sand-boxed for security, so you might not be able to interact with the filesystem in the way that you want.

If you have enough control over the target machine, you might be able to ensure that some console app or windows service is also running on the machine, and you can send http requests to that app so that it can do things that your UWP app can't.

Comment: So in that case will not I be able to set the folder path alone?